# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in ormlite with Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ormlite

I made new Android library project and I copied all sources of github project of ormlite and when I tried to run my project I got this exception

```
 TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, App.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Entity.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Term.class);

            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, User.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Department.class);
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.imona.store.entities.Department
            at com.imona.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:72)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:207)

However there is no problem with other classes

I used multidex becuase my project is very big , when I used ormlite library I was getting LoggerFactory class not found

any suggestion to solve this problem ?

Comment: what is the version of ormlite jars ?

Comment: I am using latest version

Comment: İ removed some libs and mutidex .. It works

Comment: how it is resolved. Please update your question or put your answer to help others.